# How to obtain username when connecting SQL Server using AAD Token authentication?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, authentication

Our application connects to SQL Server using AAD Token based authentication. Unlike Windows/SQL Server authentications, SYSTEM_USER function returns some key like "08b9f1b0-b2b8-49b5-83a0-3d28c10ae393@72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47" when connected using AAD Token based authentication. That said, is there any TSQL function to get user principal associated with AAD Token?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37774858/get-username-linked-to-azure-ad-bearer-token) provide any insights?

Comment: Does SESSION_USER give the same or does it resolve to something useful?

Comment: Both the suggestions doesn't work. We are planning to pass the username from middle-tier to database to work around this issue for now.